# .NET - Strategy for multi database support

Tags: .net, database, nhibernate, architecture

Our current web application is using SQL Server, we have a requirement for support Oracle now.

There are a few options:

1. Data Facade pattern: use Data Facade interface in Business Layer, so SQL Server and Oracle can have their own implementation of Data Access Layer. The problem is it's hard to synchronize DAL code for different type of database.
2. nHibernate: it seems promising, I don't have experience using it. As our current Data Access Layer is mixed with SQL and Stored Procedure, not sure whether there will be a lot of work involved if change to nHibernate (we are facing time pressure).

I'd like to hear your opinions. Thanks.

Comment: How about a combination of Entity Framework 4.0 and interface-based Dependency Injection? In order do overcome the 'problem' of synchronizing DAL code for Oracle/SS, use LINQ. (LINQ-SQL for SS, and there is a LINQ-Oracle project on Codeplex). Your interface would return LINQ types (IQueryable for example) which both repositories should adhere to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody has mentioned the [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) yet. I haven't used it so I can't provide a recommendation but I would have thought it warranted further attention. I was listening to a podcast the other day where they were stating that database inter-operability was a design goal.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why it would be so hard to have a DAL that supports both Oracle and SQL Server. Specifically, [LLBLGen](http://www.llblgen.com/defaultgeneric.aspx) does it. If it were me, I would use it. But that's because I've used it before and I'm a big fan.

Comment: That's what we do.  While in practice we have only used 1 database, we've tested switching from Sql Server to Oracle, MySql, and PostgreSQL with no issues.  LLBLGen is pretty cool like that.

Answer (score 1):

NHibernate has **excellent** support for multi-db applications. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626247/recommendations-for-supporting-both-oracle-and-sql-server-in-the-same-asp-net-app/2626552#2626552) is a post on things to consider when doing that.

However, if you have "time pressure" and you are updating an application with a completely different approach (using Stored Procedures), it will definitely be non-trivial to do the change.

Comment: Stored procedures is not that hard to fix in nhibernate

Comment: @jgauffin It depends. NH supports some ways of using SPs, but relying on them for data access is just painful.

Comment: I haven't used them, just read some articles about nhibernate and stored procedures. Can you elaborate on why they are painful?

Comment: Because you have to do a LOT of additional work to make sure they work, including verifying the order of the parameters. Plus, there are several restrictions on what the SPs can do that you need to be aware of, and most important of all, you can't do ad-hoc eager loading.

Answer (score 0):

ODP.NET provides standard ADO.NET data access, while exposing Oracle database-specific features, such as XML DB, data access performance optimizations, and Real Application Clusters connection pooling.