# EF vs NHibernate with Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, nhibernate, orm

This is not another one of the "holy-war" questions. It is concrete and is absolutely answarable.

Base asumption for this question is that noth NHibernate and Entity Framework 4.3 Code First work well with MS SQL SERVER.

It came to my attention that people are having problems with usign the Entity Framework 4.3 Code First in conjunction with Oracle RDBMS. Several fundamental problems exits and seemless integration is not-yet possible.

It the same true for NHibernate, or will I be able to switch between MS SQL and Oracle Data Providers seemlessly knowing my application works well with either product when I use NHibernate as my ORM framework?

UPDATE: The problems that others had with using the EF with Oracle are derived from the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871879/entity-framework-code-first-for-oracle) question. In particular this user's problem hasn't been resolved yet: 
[Oracle ODP.Net and EF CodeFirst - SaveChanges Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930487/oracle-odp-net-and-ef-codefirst-savechanges-error)

Comment: Your application will never work seamlessly with either RDBMS. They implement many things differently...

Comment: Thanks, Ben. So no switching between MS SQL and Oracle even with a "100-years-old" NHibernate?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov, without specific facts the question is neither concrete, nor answerable. I'll hold my closing vote to give you a chance to specify what the problems with EF+Oracle are. Also, switching databases is never 100% seamless; you should specify your requirements.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, I've added the particular example of an unanswered question on EF-Oracle operation, but this isn't the one I've face. I am checking in advance to see if I'll be able to get a seamless RDBMS "switching" from someone who has actually managed to get one working.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov, that particular case is handled well by NHibernate, but it's not clear if it's really a bug or wrong usage. If you want an *opinion*, NH is more mature and works better across RDBMS's, but the complexity of switching depends on how you use it. See my answer on [Recommendations for supporting both Oracle and SQL Server in the same ASP.NET app with NHibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2626552/62024)

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, Thanks. I think that answers it + most likely there won't be any more informative material towards this question, so you should go ahead and add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching databases is never 100% seamless. NH is more mature and works better across RDBMS's, but the complexity of switching depends on how you use it.

See my answer on [Recommendations for supporting both Oracle and SQL Server in the same ASP.NET app with NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626552/62024)